# Tabulate Intersection

Tags: arcmap, intersection, tabulate

I'm attempting to calculate land use mix and in order to do so I need the proportion of each land use within each polygon zone. When i use the tabulate intersection tool I get proportions that are more than 100% not sure what the issue is could anyone help?

Comment: How much are the summed values off of 100%? If your zones are vectors, then they are first rasterized and then compared to your landcover data. Depending on the size of your zones, the raster resolution, and how the pixels line up with your zone boundaries, you could get a slight over/under estimation of area compared to the calculated area of the polygon.

Comment: Lovette is correct. Arc converts to raster on the fly, and there's not direct way of knowing what cell size and/or snapping they use. So, it's best to convert your polygons to rasters under your own control...and then to run your zonal stats. Either way, you may end up with values >100% for smaller polygons.